# .Net Core on Heroku with Docker

Tags: docker, heroku, .net-core, dockerfile

### Context

I'm trying to deploy a **aspnet core** sample-app on [Heroku](https://heroku.com/) with docker but is not working.

repo: https://github.com/mykeels/sample-web-api
guide: https://blog.devcenter.co/deploy-asp-net-core-2-0-apps-on-heroku-eea8efd918b6

### Envoriment

**Framework** .NET Core 2.1.201
**SO:** W10 Build 17134.1
**Docker:** Docker for Windows Version 18.03.1-ce-win65(17513)

### Steps I did

**dotnet publish**
[image]

**docker build**
[image]

**Heroku Login**
[image]

**Tag and Push**
[image]

**Docker File**
[image]

**App on Heroku**
[image]

**Not running**
[image]

**I Also tried this:**
[image]

## Question: What is wrong ?

Comment: Try replacing `CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet Blogifier.Web.dll` with `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blogifier.Web.dll"]` in Dockerfile. Also, I noticed that in the dotnet publish screenshot the dll name is SampleWebApi.dll not `Blogifier.Web.dll`so please ensure that dll name is correct

Comment: is not the dll name. I tried with two differents apps. Will try change the CMD to ENTRYPOINT

Comment: @MohsinMehmood didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION

First: Replace the `docker tag` and `docker push` commands with:

```
heroku container: push web -a <app-name>
```

That's when I discovered that the **heroku registry** connection was not set up.

*Command to configure:*

```
heroku container: login
```

*This command only works with windows on the default terminal (does not work in **cmder** with bash).*

*or the command*

```
docker login --username = _ --password = $ (heroku auth: token) registry.heroku.com
```

#### Now, just carry out the following commands.

*Push*

```
heroku container: push web -a <app-name>
//example:
heroku container: push web -a sample-web-carlos
```

*Release*

```
heroku container: release web -a <app-name>
//example:
heroku container: release web -sample-web-carlos
```

*read more:*
*https://github.com/heroku/heroku-container-registry/issues/45

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime*

Thank mohsin Mehmood for your help!

Comment: I followed the mentioned guide step by step and didn't face any issue except that I had to run `heroku release` command. If you notice in the guide it is mentioned to execute `heroku login` and `heroku container:login` commands before `docker tag` and `docker push` commands. `heroku container:login` command is necessary to be able to push to heroku registry and may be thats why you were getting that no basic auth credentials error

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way you could make this work with Heroku.

**Create a Dockerfile in the root of your solution**

```
#https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples/aspnetapp

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet [THE NAME OF YOUR FILE].dll
```

---

**Create a simple batch file (Assumed Windows OS) called "*publish.bat*"**

**NOTE** - When **dotnet clean** is ran, it doesn't clean out the publish folder. I recommend you delete the contents of the directory before publishing. You can add it to the batch file as you see fit.

```
REM - This file assumes that you have access to the application and that you have docker installed
REM : Setup your applications name below
SET APP_NAME=""

REM - Delete all files and folders in publish
del /q ".\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\*"
FOR /D %%p IN (".\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q

dotnet clean --configuration Release
dotnet publish -c Release
copy Dockerfile .\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
cd .\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
call heroku container:login
call heroku container:push web -a %APP_NAME%
call heroku container:release web -a %APP_NAME%
```

---

**From the root of your solution, now just run publish.bat**

```
c:\dev\my-amazing-app\publish.bat
```

Information:

- Heroku - Docker Instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

Comment: Nice answer - it helped me! But my script is stopping at the heroku container:login, after the Login Succeeded message. How to avoid that?

Comment: Never mind, adding "call" before each heroku command solves this. Maybe you could add that to your example. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to figure it out https://simple-web-mohsin.herokuapp.com/api/values

1. No need for `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blogifier.Web.dll"]` change as suggested above.
2. After docker push command, you need to run release command as per [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1426)

So run the following command after docker push command

```
heroku container:release web --app={app name}
```

for my case it was

```
heroku container:release web --app=simple-web-mohsin
```

**Note:** word web in above command is process type and needs to be input as it is.

Comment: see the new printscreen. Maybe is something with "no basic auth credentials" but I logeed in it before that command.

Comment: In your initial question it was not mentioned that push command was failing. So I proposed solution assuming that docker push was working. heroku:login command was required before pushing to heroku registry. Anyways it’s good that your issue is resolved

Comment: Look the printscreen of the initial post. It is there on "tag and push".

Comment: Ok in the initial post printscreen, I can not see the the error `Docker push exited with 1` only  no basic auth credentials.