# Application Error on Heroku with Docker and Asp.net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, heroku, dockerfile

I am hosting an asp.net core api on Heroku using Docker and github actions.

When the actions runs, everything is fine and the app is deployed. After I go to the url, I have an **Application Error** message.
Here is the concerned part in my logs

```
2022-02-17T16:41:54.949789+00:00 app[web.1]: [16:41:54 DBG] Failed to bind to http://[::]:80 (IPv6Any). Attempting to bind to http://0.0.0.0:80 instead.
2022-02-17T16:41:54.966069+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied
```

After some searchs, I have found [this post](https://habr.com/en/post/450904/), [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434242/asp-net-core-gives-system-net-sockets-socketexception-error-on-heroku) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004285/net-core-on-heroku-with-docker) saying to set the port in the Program.cs file or to set `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT` in the Dockerfile. I have tried both but nothing worked.
Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PeerNotation.Api.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "PeerNotation.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src"
RUN dotnet build "PeerNotation.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PeerNotation.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PeerNotation.Api.dll"]
```

and the code snippet from my Program.cs file

```cs
var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
builder.WebHost.UseUrls($"http://*:{port}");
```

(I have tried to log the port and it is never null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researchs, i have found that I was setting the port using the wrong way.
I should add the url to the `WebApplication` object like this :

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
    app.Urls.Add($"http://*:{port}");
}
```

And now, the app uses the correct port.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As mentioned here [asp net core 6.0 kestrel server is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532898/asp-net-core-6-0-kestrel-server-is-not-working), .NET 6 does not use UseUrls() anymore.

Following the guide from the mentioned link I added this snippet to my Program.cs:

```
var portExists = int.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"), out var port);
if (portExists)
{
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ListenAnyIP(port);
    });
}
```

After deployment application started working without errors in Heroku.